# Setting Table with irregular headers in has map in java

Tags: java, html, hashmap

I am new in java, i want to set table irregular headers in the hashmap. Till now, i can set normal headers and content of the table using hash map

```
//~~ Definig headers variable
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

//~~ Setting headers data
headers.put("country", "From Country");
headers.put("city", "From City");

headers.put("tocountry", "To Country");
headers.put("tocity", "To City");
```

This is generating normal headers that's fine, but i want to add col-span = 2 i.e two headings should come under one main heading such as country and city heading should come From Place heading.

thanks

I am attaching the screenshot what i want.

[image: desired table format]

Comment: *This is generating normal headers that's fine,* That's strange, as your first two `put`s will do nothing as they will be overwritten by the next two

Comment: Note that a hashmap is a _data structure_ whereas what you want is a table/graphical representation. Those are 2 different things. - Also note that a hashmap is unordered, i.e. when iterating you might get "country", "tocity", "city", "tocountry" or something else - What you "might" want to do is define the UI table in your html as you want and do a _lookup_ in the hashmap for each cell and using the cell's corresponding key.

Comment: You're not telling us what this is -  a client-side app, a web app or what?

Comment: It is a web-app

Comment: Well there could be many ways to put up a table with headers like that

Answer (score 0):

## Use the Power of Objects

`HashMap` is not the proper way of storing the data in this case.

Collections are containers of independent units of data, when you're trying to use a Collection in order to combine a set of properties together that's an indicator that you're misusing a collection and these correlated properties should constitute an Object.

Creating custom objects gives several advantages:

- Object provides a clear and transparant structure to the data;
- Ability to use proper data types for each property;
- Ability to introduce a custom behavior;
- Less error-prone (with map, you can mess around with the keys).

That's how your data can be represented as a `class`:

```
public class Travel {
    private String fromCountry;
    private String fromCity;
    private String toCountry;
    private String toCity;
    
    // constructors, getters
}
```

If you're concerned about representing the data as a string formatted in a certain way. Then you easily customize string representation of your objects, as well serialization into formats JSON.